# hyperledger fabric rest API to smart contract

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am making a custom API endpoint to my hyperledger fabric smart contract and i am using postman to test. The post is status of 200 but throws and error of cant read submitTransaction() function how to fix this error

terminal error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'submitTransaction' of undefined
at Object.exports.invoke(/home/hlf/dpt_old/webapp/api/network.js:133:50)
at router.post (/home/hlf/dpt_old/web-app/api/routes/members.js:32:34)at <anonymous>at process._tickCallback(internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
POST /members/ 200 88.465 ms - 386
```

postman error:

```
"message": "Cannot read property 'submitTransaction' of undefined",
"stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'submitTransaction' of undefined\n    at Object.exports.invoke (/home/hlf/dpt_old/web-app/api/network.js:133:50)\n    at router.post (/home/hlf/dpt_old/web-app/api/routes/members.js:32:34)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)"
```

Comment: it seems like there is some issue while requiring the contract instance,can you share the part of code for better debugging?

Comment: Please share the code that is submitting the transaction. Please ensure that you have an identity in your wallet (public + private keys), that you are referencing the deployed smart contract that is installed on the peers, and make sure you are referencing your connection profile which outlines all of the URLs for the relevant network components such as the peer, orderer, CA, etc. You can check a correct implementation of how to correctly submit a transaction here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/fabcar/javascript/invoke.js